# Plotting a histogram by percentiles

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any library to plot a histogram by percentiles based on a series? I have been digging around pandas but i do not see any available methods for such. I do know of a long workaround which is to manually calculate the number of occurences for each percentile i want. But i think there probably is a better solution.

Currently what i have to get the individual counts

```
# Sample series 
tenth = df.col.quantile(0.1) 
twenty = df.col.quantile(0.2) 
twenty_count = len(twenty - tenth)
```

And so on...

However using describe. I manage to get this

```
df.describe(percentiles = [x/10.0 for x in range(1,11)]
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample like `np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(20,1)), columns=['col'])
print (df)` with desired output? Or please accept anser if helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.col.rank(pct=True).hist()
```

However, this is a bad idea.

Consider the following dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        col=np.random.randn(1000),
        col2=np.random.rand(1000)
    ))
```

Then

```
df.col.rank(pct=True).hist()
```

[image]

Which is a silly graph.

Instead, divide by the maximum absolute value

```
(df / df.abs().max()).hist()
```

[image]